# _isUrlInternal method in Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action failing due to port number

Tags: url, routing

i am implementing the currency switcher on my 1.5.1.0 CE site. it's a fairly straightforward implementation, but for some reason, once i select a currency, i get redirected to the homepage rather than the page i was one.

i narrowed it down to the fact that the method _isUrlInternal is failing due to the port number being in the referring url. i'm definitely not using port numbers explicitly (using the standard 80/443).

can anyone think of a reason why it would be evaluating port numbers?

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy. Ie. Varnish/Nginx before PHP/Apache? It might be worth doing `var_dump($_SERVER);` to confirm the values of `HTTP_HOST` and `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: nope, just a standard apache config. neither HTTP_HOST or REMOTE_ADDR have the port listed.

Comment: Then if its not there, I would guess someone has changed core code. All I could suggest is `grep`ing the `code` and `lib` dirs for the existence of the post being defined.

Comment: i think it's coming from getCurrentUrl() in the core helper:

`$port = $request->getServer('SERVER_PORT');
if ($port) {
  if ($port == Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT) {
    $port = '';
  } else {
    $port = ':' . $port;
  }
}`

since i'm on SSL when i'm on the cart :\

Comment: Can you test in a non-port enviro for DDx?

Comment: i'm using standard ports (80 and 443), so not sure how i'd do that? in my vhost maybe?

Comment: Sorry, misread - thought you were using nonstandard ports. If you tweak `getCurrentUrl()` does it solve your problem?

Comment: yes. for some reason, magento doesn't seem to include 443 as a default port (or doesn't check for it).

Comment: @Laura would you mind posting your comment as an answer now that you have enough rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason, magento doesn't seem to include 443 as a default port (or doesn't check for it).

getCurrentUrl() in the core helper:

```
$port = $request->getServer('SERVER_PORT');
if ($port) {
  if ($port == Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT) {
    $port = '';
  }
  else {
    $port = ':' . $port;
  }
}
```